# I asked whether a feature in a game was an Easter Egg of a famous TV series, is this on topic?

Tags: discussion

[I asked whether a feature in a game was an Easter Egg](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/233169/is-the-notification-sound-used-in-puzzle-pirates-a-copy-of-the-notification-soun) of a famous TV series, is this on topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately no. The only way to know if this is an Easter Egg is to know if the developer intended it to be one. There are lots of clear cut cases where things are Easter Eggs or references or clearly point to something that can be well understood outside developer intent. This particular case, however is not. As such, it is off-topic.

Comment: Wouldn't many enthusiasts of the game perhaps know about documentation which might have been published somewhere by fans or developers which have confirmed the Easter Egg in question? Documentation which might not be easy to find right now on Google?

Comment: @JonathanTodd Yes, but there is no knowing *if* that information exists. Basically, the only way to know this information is for a developer to confirm it themselves. Which we have deemed off-topic here because those questions are unanswerable a lot of the time, and even when they are answerable, they tend to not be good questions overall for the system.

Comment: @JonathanTodd Basically, the questions are bad because there is no correct, verifiable answer. We can't say yes and we can't say no. There is only one person (or team) in the world who can, and we can't have any expectation they are on the site. So these questions exist in a nebulous unanswerable state potentially forever. Or at least until someone asks the developer this question specifically.

Comment: Additionally, for things like sound effects, it would be very difficult for anyone not on the design team to confirm. Even if we isolated the Boatswain's Whistle sound from Star Trek, and found it to be an exact match of the notification sound from Puzzle Pirates... Was that an intended reference? If TV shows and Video Games have one thing in common, is that they both often make use of sound effects packages - partly because it's far cheaper than custom recording every bang, zap, chirp, buzz, or whatever you might need.

Comment: TOS used the whistle as a distinctive and hard to miss sound (even over the din of whatever else might be happening aboard) to precede important ship-wide messages to the crew. This (roughly) reflects its [historical usage](http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Boatswain's_whistle). Puzzle Pirates also uses the whistle to indicate notifications - and being a (mostly) naval themed game set in the era of tallships, the boatswain's whistle makes sense. It is just as likely that the same whistle sound effect is in whatever package both properties utilize, and both use it (somewhat) properly.

Comment: @TrentHawkins - I can confirm at least one instance of two different productions (game/TV) using the same sound effects package: Stargate Atlantis and Fallout 3. I noticed it the other night: Atlantis uses the same 'pull the gun out of the holster' sound as in Fallout 3 - in at least one (but probably more) episodes.

Comment: @Robotnik Yeah, It's more or less the sound equivalent of [Neon Tubes](http://pearlsofgeekdom.com/?tag=neon-tubes), a generic prop that's been popping up film wherever "futuristic" tech is needed for over 30 years.